# MySQL JOIN Query Help : join two tables with distinct right table rows ordered in descending order

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, one for complaints and the other for assigning technicians

Table 1 :- *`complaints`*

```
------------------------------------------
| id | complaint      | charges | status |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | gas kit broken | 250     |  2     |
| 2  | water leakage  | 100     |  2     |
| 3  | too much smoke | 150     |  2     |
------------------------------------------
```

Now, for 1 complaint many technicians can get assigned 1 after another until complaint is solved so

Table 2 :- *`assign`*

```
------------------------------------------------
| id | complaint_id | technician | assign_date |
------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1            | 24         | 1391904000  |
| 2  | 1            | 55         | 1391598500  |*
| 3  | 2            | 20         | 1391600000  |
| 4  | 2            | 31         | 1391676500  |
| 5  | 2            | 25         | 1391665000  |*
| 6  | 3            | 26         | 1391682000  |
| 7  | 3            | 28         | 1391800000  |*
------------------------------------------------
```

what i want is join all rows of complaint with status=1 to last rows of assign where `complaints`.id=`assign`.complaint_id.

I've marked them with stars (*) so the output shud be

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | complaint      | charges | status | id | complaint_id | technician | assign_date |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | gas kit broken | 250     |  2     | 2  | 1            | 55         | 1391598500  |
| 2  | water leakage  | 100     |  2     | 5  | 2            | 25         | 1391665000  |
| 3  | too much smoke | 150     |  2     | 7  | 3            | 28         | 1391800000  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My working platforms are :- PHP and MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.*, b.*
from complaint as a left join
    (select c.*
     from assign as c
     where c.id in (
        select max(d.id) as max_id
        from assign as d
        group by complaint_id)) as b
        on a.id = b.complaint_id
```

Comment: Right, I'm sorry, I'm just new here that's why I don't know how to format my answer the way you did. Maybe you could teach me? Thanks!